# Will the mapping do the job if the source stream is still empty?

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart, dart-stream

In the following example I expected that if `typeOfThingSubject` was not still emited with a value than the existing not null `things` should be returned from `else` branch. Instead, in the stream builder `snapshot.data` is null.

```
// in bloc constructor
final typeOfThingSubject = BehaviorSubject<TypeOfThing?>();

// at this point the above subject still wasn't emitted with data
final filteredThings = typeOfThingSubject
    .map<Iterable<Thing>>((value) {
  if (value != null) {
    return <Thing>[...];
  } else {
    // obviously this branch should be executed but that doesn't happen
    // when typeOfThingSubject wasn't emitted with an event yet
    // and truly the `typeOfThingSubject` is just declared at this point
    return things; // existing iterable
  }
});

return Bloc._( ...
  things: filteredThings, // this is the same stream `things` as in the builder below
);

// in view
StreamBuilder<Iterable<Thing>>(
  stream: bloc.things,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    // at this point `snapshot.data` is null
    final things = snapshot.data ?? [];
    return ListView.builder( ...
```

In the definition of `filteredThings` it map over `BehaviorSubject<TypeOfThing?>` and at the moment of initialization the subject still wasn't emitted with data, so why when the execution in `map` so named part of the code the `else` branch doesn't work?

I expected that if stream `typeOfThingSubject` was still `null` then the existing `iterable` will return but it doesn't work this way.

Comment: @pskink well, I preliminarily concluded for myself that map will not be executed until at least one event occurs in the source stream

Comment: map's callback is executed on every stream event, so if original stream emits 3 values, map's callback will be called 3 times

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
if(typeOfThing == nul){
return false
}else{return true}
```